# keras BatchGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence) is too slow

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing, batch-processing

I'm using a custom batch generator with large dataframe. but the Generator takes too much time to generate a batch, it takes 127s to generate a batch of 1024. I've tried Dask but still, the processing is slow. is there any way to integrate multiprocessing with inside the generator. knowing that I've tried   `use_multiprocessing=True` with  `workers=12`

```
import keras
from random import randint
import glob
import warnings
import numpy as np
import math
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

class BatchGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, labels=None, batch_size=8, n_classes=4, shuffle=True,
            seq_len=6, data_path=None, meta_path=None,list_IDs=None):

        'Initialization'
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.labels = labels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.seq_len = seq_len
        self.meta_df = meta_path
        self.data_df = data_path
        self.data_df = self.data_df.astype({"mjd": int})
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        if self.list_IDs==None:
            self.list_IDs = list(self.meta_df['object_id'].unique())
        self.on_epoch_end()



    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        # Find list of IDs
        list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

        # Generate data
        X, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)

        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
        X_dat = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.seq_len,6,1))
        Y_mask = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.seq_len,6,1))
        # Y_dat = np.empty((self.batch_size,1), dtype=int)
        X_length= np.empty((self.batch_size,1), dtype=int)


        for i, trans_id in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
           
            curve = self.data_df[self.data_df.object_id==trans_id]
            mjdlist = list(curve['mjd'].unique())
            ts_length = len(mjdlist)
            if  ts_length <= self.seq_len :
                start_ind = 0
            else : 
                start_ind = randint(0, ts_length - self.seq_len)
                ts_length = self.seq_len
            for j in range(ts_length):
                if j+start_ind < len(mjdlist):
                    step = curve[curve.mjd==mjdlist[j+start_ind]]
                for k in range(len(step.mjd)):
                    obs = step[step.passband==k]
                    if len(obs) == 0 :
                        # print('here is one')
                        continue
                    else: 
                        if k == 0:
                            X_dat[i,j,0,0] =obs.flux.iloc[0]
                            Y_mask[i,j,0,0] = 1
                        if  k == 1:
                            X_dat[i,j,1,0] = obs.flux.iloc[0]
                            Y_mask[i,j,1,0] = 1
                        if  k == 2:
                            X_dat[i,j,2,0] = obs.flux.iloc[0]
                            Y_mask[i,j,2,0] = 1
                        if  k == 3:
                            X_dat[i,j,3,0] = obs.flux.iloc[0]
                            Y_mask[i,j,3,0] = 1
                        if  k == 4:
                            X_dat[i,j,4,0] = obs.flux.iloc[0]
                            Y_mask[i,j,4,0] = 1
                        if  k == 5:
                            X_dat[i,j,5,0] = obs.flux.iloc[0]
                            Y_mask[i,j,5,0] = 1
            # meta = self.meta_df[self.meta_df['object_id'] == trans_id]
            # Y_dat[i] = self.labels[int(meta['target'])]
            X_length[i,0] = ts_length
            flux_max = np.max(X_dat[i])
            flux_min = np.min(X_dat[i])
            flux_pow = math.log2(flux_max - flux_min)
            X_dat[i] /= flux_pow 
        X_noised  = X_dat + np.random.uniform(low=0, high=0.5, size=X_dat.shape)
      
        return [X_noised, X_length, np.reshape(Y_mask,(self.batch_size, self.seq_len*6))],  np.reshape(X_dat,(self.batch_size, self.seq_len*6))
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it faster, the for loop in the function `__data_generation` should be parallelized. Using the `joblib` package may help.